# Facebook Integration in Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app already registered with store. Now I have converted the phone app to an universal app but when trying to integrate Facebook for the windows 8.1 app it returns an error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

In Facebook developer site I have created an app with Windows Platform and store id as callback Uri of phone app. How can the same Facebook app be associated with Windows 8.1 app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the same experience when developing windows stoe app as you implement facebook integration in windows phone app.

We need to follow the steps(using [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx)) mentioned [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/facebook-login-for-windows-store-apps/) for windows store app. And you may found how different the facebook login is for windows store app and windows phone app from [this article](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/login/).